# How do you import in Clojure nested Java classes that are in separate files?

Tags: java, clojure

For example SearcherServer and SearcherClient are in separate files:

https://github.com/linkedin/indextank-engine/tree/master/src/main/java/com/flaptor/indextank/rpc

And in Java, SearcherClient is used within its main method like this:

```
Searcher.Client client = new Searcher.Client(protocol);
```

https://github.com/linkedin/indextank-engine/blob/master/src/main/java/com/flaptor/indextank/rpc/SearcherClient.java#L106

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer to Searcher.Client as `com.flaptor.indextank.rpc.Searcher$Client`.

Client isn't in a separate file from Searcher: they're both in the auto generated class `Searcher.java` [here](https://github.com/linkedin/indextank-engine/blob/master/gen-java/com/flaptor/indextank/rpc/Searcher.java).

Comment: I get an `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class`
 when doing: `(import '(com.flaptor.indextank.rpc Searcher$Client))`

Comment: It should work: I've just downloaded the source; run `mvn clean install`; added `[com.flaptor.indextank/indextank-engine "1.0.0"]` as a Leiningen dependency; started the REPL and run `(import '(com.flaptor.indextank.rpc Searcher$Client))`: it worked fine. How are you using the library?

Comment: It works now. I had thrift 0.8.0 as an explicit dependency, and removing it cleared things up. Thanks, Andrew.